# Javascript triggers effect even on site builder page

Tags: javascript, web

I think I need a little help here.
I'm doing my company's website through a site builder and I'm planning to add a short alert box every time you first visit the company website. So I added this:

```
<script>
alert ("Welcome to COMPANY NAME HERE");
</script>
```

But, after saving my changes in the content of that page...the JavaScript alert box was triggered even though I'm not on my company's website.

I would like that alert box to be only triggered only upon visiting the company website.
Can you guys help me with this? 
I would really appreciate the answers :)

Comment: What site were you on when the alert was triggered?

Comment: The site builder's site. I can't put the screenshot because I only have 6 reputation here, StackOverflow needs 10 reps before I can put images

Comment: I'm pretty sure that's expected behavior; if you're on the sitebuilder still, it's probably showing you your website in an iframe of sorts. If you really want, you can `alert` only when `window.location.href = [yourwebsite's URL]`

Comment: so i'm gonna use an if-else statement here?

Comment: Yeah that can work. Although, I don't see the point of having it on the long term :P

Comment: Why do you want to do this? I'd find it really annoying as a site visitor.

Comment: I just wanted something to welcome the site visitors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably want to invoke the alert on `ready` so try:

```
(function() {
    if ( window.location.href == "www.yourdomain.com" ) {
        alert("Welcome to COMPANY NAME HERE");
    }
}());
```